# MacOS With Python 3.6 ImageTk not displaying images

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library

I've been working on a gui for this application and it looked fine on Windows before with the code shown below. However for some reason when I run the same code on my Mac, there is just a blank space where the photo is supposed to be. The code I am using to generate the area where the photo is is shown below.

```
csvarea = Frame(top)
pluggy = Image.open(r'./pluggy.png').convert("RGBA").resize((115, 125))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pluggy)
plabel = Label(csvarea, image=img)
plabel.img = img
plabel.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
loadtitle = Label(csvarea, text="CSV status", font="TkDefaultFont 16 bold")
loadtitle.pack(fill="y", expand=True)
plabel.bind("<Button-1>", trap)
csvstatus = Label(csvarea, textvariable=loadstatus)
csvstatus.pack()
availfields = Label(csvarea, textvariable=available)
availfields.pack(fill="y", expand=True)
```

When I run the program on Windows 10, I get the GUI that can be found on my README.md [here](https://github.com/quietimcoding/pluggy). On Mac, however, it looks like this:

[Screenshot of Pluggy on MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSGBr.png)

Any ideas would be appreciated.